# Is there any way to disable x509 certificate verification process ONLY for CRL checks

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

We have some local machines that can only access a certain server. We use an app on these local machines that talks to this certain server. The problem is the application is a remote support tool that gets installed everytime you use it and removes itself everytime your done with a support session. Each time it connects when it executes the file x509 handles the code signing cert validation process and needs to reach out to the CRL's. So as you may have guessed validation fails and the app won't run. Is there a way, outside of re-coding x509, to keep it from trying to check the CRL's so I can get these apps to work?

Comment: X509 is the standard. What implementation of the standard does the program use, as options like this are implementation-dependent?

Comment: X509Certificate2:- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.verify(v=vs.110).aspx - And the app does not deviate from this AFAIK

Comment: I'm no expert in this field or I'd post an answer, but that link says "Note that the default chaining engine can be overridden using the CryptoConfig class." I expect that is what you'd have to do.